# What is the reason for the odd vowel values of Japanese ココア?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, loanwords

I've done a bit of digging, and for the life of me, I cannot find any clear record or explanation for why Japanese ココア is pronounced the way it is.

Sources researched to date:

- Lots of different sources at [the Kotobank entry for ココア](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A2-64514), including Britannica Japan, Daijisen, Kokugo Dai Jiten, MyPedia, Chocolate / Cocoa Dictionary, etc etc.
- Lots of different sources at [the Kotobank entry for カカオ](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AA-43283)
- [Chocolate & Cocoa Association of Japan's site](http://www.chocolate-cocoa.com/dictionary/history/japan/j01_a.html)
- [Snippets from the journal of Tokugawa Akitake](https://books.google.com/books?id=pQc0AQAAIAAJ&dq=%22%E5%BE%B3%E5%B7%9D%E6%98%AD%E6%AD%A6%E5%B9%95%E6%9C%AB%E6%BB%9E%E6%AC%A7%E6%97%A5%E8%A8%98%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A2) (1853–1910), listed as a source on the Chocolate & Cocoa Association's page, wherein Akitake described drinking ココア one morning when visiting the Paris World Fair in 1868, as listed also in [the Japanese Wikipedia article about him](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BE%B3%E5%B7%9D%E6%98%AD%E6%AD%A6#%E8%A8%AA%E6%AC%A7%E4%BD%BF%E7%AF%80%E5%9B%A3)

Lots of information is out there about カカオ and ココア, and what each of them are, and how the former is turned into the latter.  I can confirm in various sources that カカオ is borrowed from Spanish, and ココア is borrowed from English.  But I can find nothing about why ココア is pronounced as //ko.ko.a//.

My suspicion is that this is the result of "book pronunciation", based on the English spelling *cocoa* and simply reading it out vowel-for-vowel.  A distant alternative possibility is that the Japanese word somehow metathesized the vowels after borrowing *cacao*, the common term for this in many other European languages, including the Japanese-contact trifecta of Dutch, Spanish, and Portuguese.  English wound up with a pronunciation of //ˈkoʊ.koʊ// (US) or //ˈkəʊ.kəʊ// (UK) not through any metathesis, but rather through early confusion with *coco* (as in *coconut*), as best I can tell.  (See also [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocoa#English).)  If ココア were borrowed from spoken English, we'd expect something more like //kóꜜò.kòò//, instead of the //kóꜜ.kò.à// and //kó.kóꜜ.à// pronunciations evident in modern usage.

Does anyone have any solid evidence for why we have this unexpected word form?  Or any leads on academics or references that discuss this oddity of etymology?

Comment: Does this [森永製菓](https://www.morinaga.co.jp/yomu-cocoa/trivia/vol08.html#:~:text=%E3%81%9D%E3%82%82%E3%81%9D%E3%82%82%E3%80%8C%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AA%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B3%E6%96%B9,%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%82%AB%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E3%81%8C%E8%AA%9E%E6%BA%90%E3%80%82&text=%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AB%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E5%B8%B0%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F,%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%80%81%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E5%90%8D%E7%A7%B0%E3%81%8C%E5%AE%9A%E7%9D%80%E3%80%82)'s page answer your question? It seems the pronunciation comes from England.

Comment: Thanks @kimiTanaka. That link disagrees with other sources: see the etymologies at https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cacao#Spanish and https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocoa#English. See also [Johnson’s own dictionary entry from 1755](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/cocoa-2/), where he was clearly conflating _coconut_ with _cocoa_. The English pronunciation was not due to any difficulty in pronouncing _cacao_, as described on the Morinaga page. Also, though Johnson’s entry lacks any phonetic guide, _cocoa_ as read using normal English spelling rules would not be //ko.ko.a//.

Comment: I think your first conjecture is the most likely. There's a lot of examples where English words transcribe into Japanese according to how they spell as opposed to how they are pronounced. That explains the ア. Pizza is another example. ピザ. I have also lighted upon [this article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/cocoanut-vs-coconut-spelling-history) that basically confirms what you say about the English word cocoa.

Comment: I've been interested in this fact too, and read Tokugawa's diary where he allegedly drinked ココア. It was a red herring. The original text of that part is written in French. He drinked "chocolat".

Comment: No, but if you search "chocolat" on your Google Books page, it returns one result and that's it.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Translation is by the book's editors. They say that the original French text was written for his language exercise, and corrected by his tutor.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Editors of the 1999 book. It's a collection of all sorts of manuscripts during his trip. This journal was written on his notebook unpublished.

Comment: FWIW, ボタン is another word that bugs me in the same way. I mean, I would expect it to be バトン.

Comment: @jarmanso7, my copy of Daijirin sources JA ボタン from PT _botão_, where the nasal _-ão_ may well sound like アン to a Japanese ear.  Harder to find due to the lemmatization (where the word is filed), but I did just find [the KDJ entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%88%95%E3%83%BB%E9%87%A6-2082567), which also points to Portuguese as the source.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a conclusive case, but it seems like ココア was considered wrong at some point. If it was an accidental mistake that stuck, there might not be a very logical explanation.

Some old sources say ココア is a mistaken term with warped pronunciation (訛り), maintaining that コーコー is more correct.

- [「コーコー」は坊間にて「ココア」と誤稱する興奮性飮料の一なり](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/1082673?keyword=%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A2,%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC&page=63)
- [從來我邦では訛つてココアと呼んで來たが近年統計類にコーコーと改めるやうになつた](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/1029523?keyword=%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A2&page=32)
- [ココア（コーコーの訛りだ）](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/888202?keyword=%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A2,%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC&page=45)